# Install package in development mode (with R source not compiled into Rdb)

Tags: r

I need to modify `R` code in an `R` package which has a fortran binding. When I install a package I see that the repository directory has no source code but `*.Rdb` binaries instead.

I looked at the `devtools` package, but it is still unclear to me how to install the package without compiling R source part, analogously to python:

```
python setup.py develop
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no (easy) way of doing what you're after. The easiest is to find package source, modify FORTRAN part and recompile. It's easy `R CMD build package_tarball.tar.gz`.

Comment: I don't need to modify Fortran code. Only R.

Comment: From what I know about package development, you're "doomed" to recompiling, sorry.

Comment: If its an exported, top-level function that you want to edit, then just dump its source out, edit, reload it. You might get some problems because its no longer in the package namespace but careful application of `originalpackage:::unexportedfunction` can call unexported functions from the original package. More details?

Comment: how do you reload it? I need to call the package from `rpy` API.

Comment: `help("assignInNamespace")`?